# How to access default context menu item of your chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was wondering how you would access the default context menu item for your chrome extension (which is greyed out in my case) which I want to use to redirect to my chrome:extension page onclick.

background.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    if (info.menuItemId === 'MONEN') {

        console.log('My context menu item was clicked!');
    }
});
```

manifest.json

```
...
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
}, ...
```

[image]

Comment: There's no way, but you can set a URL in manifest.json's `homepage_url` key so it'll be opened when this item is clicked (it's probably limited to http/https). BTW "Manage extension" item does what you want.